# adding percentage label to Bokeh Pie chart

Tags: python, bokeh, pie-chart

I want to add percentage as a label to my Bokeh donut chart. I have accomplished it! with a bit of mathematics! but I think that there must be a better built-in solution. I saw some solutions but they were from an older version of Bokeh and did not work for me. I am sharing my code and result:

```
from math import pi
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum 
from bokeh.models import Legend, HoverTool, LabelSet
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

value = [10,20,30,40]*5

data = {'name': ["A", "B","C","D"]*5,                               
        'value': value,                     
        'angle': [v/sum(value)*2*pi for v in value],
        'cumulative_angle':[(sum(value[0:i+1])- (item/2))/sum(value)*2*pi for i,item in enumerate(value)],
        'percentage': [d/sum(value)*100 for d in value],
        'color': Category10[5][1:]*5}      

data['label'] = ["{:.0f}%".format(p) for p in data['percentage']]
data['cos'] = np.cos(data['cumulative_angle'])*0.3
data['sin'] = np.sin(data['cumulative_angle'])*0.3

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)


TOOLTIPS = [ 
  ("Value", "@value"),
  ("Percentage", "@percentage{0.2f}%")
] 


p = figure(plot_height=600,plot_width=600,x_range=(-1,1), y_range=(-1,1), tools='hover',
           tooltips=TOOLTIPS, title="My Donut Chart", toolbar_location=None)


r = p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=0, inner_radius=0.2, outer_radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', fill_alpha=1, source=source)


legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=dict(field="name"), renderers=[r])], location=(0, 80)) 
p.add_layout(legend, 'right') 


labels = LabelSet(x='cos', y='sin', text="label", y_offset=0,
          text_font_size="6pt", text_color="black",
          source=source, text_align='center')

p.add_layout(labels)


p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None


show(p)
```

[the current Pie chart with percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILWnb.png)

Although I think that this is mathematically right, it doesn't always work! It might be because of inner dimensions of Bokeh. For instance if you change the width and the height the percentages might scatter around, and you would need to set y_offset etc. to fix it. I don't want that! What is the correct way of implementing it?

Thanks

Comment: I have posted a solution for a pie chart a couple of weeks ago. The labels aren't centered, but they won't be plotted outside the wedges. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892890/adding-labels-in-pie-chart-wedge-in-bokeh/54004446#54004446

Comment: thanks, your solution is not also completely insensitive to the dimension but it's better than mine. However, it rotates the labels which make them more difficult to read and could be confusing. The position of the label is not also at its best. Using ```text_align = 'center'``` in the LabelSet you used make it a bit better. If you take a look at my solution it seems okay as you can determine the position of labels easily and text is horizontal. That'd be great if we could fix the minor issue there or come up with a more built-in solution!

Comment: I found an inbuild solution with Bokeh, but it would require you to use JavaScript. You can find a nice example on this page: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#bokeh-charts-pie

Comment: great! good to know ... it seems that it is completely in JavaScript ... in the best case I guess I can provide my data with Python. Do you know if it's possible to show such plot in Jupyter Notebook? That would be good as well if we accomplish this by adding some JavaScript code to our Python code (Pie chart), not writing it in JavaScript completely