# Bokeh pie chart show percentage labels upside down

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a dataframe with amounts grouped by categories and I want to generate a pie chart containing the percentages per category. I am using the Bokeh library in Python.

My problem is that some percetange labels are not displayed properly in the pie chart as shown in the following image.
[image]

Here is the code that I use to produce the pie chart:

```
df['angle'] = df['paymentAmount'] / df['paymentAmount'].sum() * 2 * pi
if len(df.index) > 2:
    df["color"] = GnBu[len(df.index)]
elif len(df.index) == 2:
    df["color"] = ["steelblue", "skyblue"]
else:
    df["color"] = ["steelblue"]
df["percentage"] = df["paymentAmount"] / df["paymentAmount"].sum()
df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n))
df["percentage"] = df['percentage'].astype(str)
df["percentage"] = df["percentage"].str.pad(35, side="left")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(width=figsize[0], height=figsize[1], toolbar_location=None,
           tooltips=[("percentage", "@percentage")],
           tools="hover", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))
pie_chart = p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4,
                    start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
                    line_color="white", fill_color='color', source=source)
labels = LabelSet(x=0, y=1, text='percentage', angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), source=source,
                  render_mode='canvas')
p.add_layout(labels)

legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=dict(field='category'), renderers=[pie_chart])],
                location=(0, figsize[1] - 100))
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

p.axis.axis_label = None
p.axis.visible = False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None
save(p)
```

Some data to reproduce the the pie chart above (tab separated)

```
category    paymentAmount
Chemicals   52800.95001766206
Research    110878.70999269483
Construction    266189.2100121978
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found two useful StackOverflow posts to solve this:

- In LabelSet you have to set the angle as zero so as not to rotate the labels ([Adding labels to bokeh pie chart wedge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826103/adding-labels-to-bokeh-pie-chart-wedge?rq=1))
- You have to calculate the coordinates (x and y) of LabelSet for each item. For this I used this post: [adding percentage label to Bokeh Pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314926/adding-percentage-label-to-bokeh-pie-chart)

Therefore, I have modified your code as follows:

```
df['angle'] = df['paymentAmount'] / df['paymentAmount'].sum() * 2 * pi
value = list(df["paymentAmount"])
df["cumulative_angle"] = [(sum(value[0:i + 1]) - (item / 2)) / sum(value) * 2 * pi for i, item in enumerate(value)]
df['cos'] = np.cos(df['cumulative_angle']) * 0.3
df['sin'] = np.sin(df['cumulative_angle']) * 0.3
if len(df.index) > 2:
    df["color"] = GnBu[len(df.index)]
elif len(df.index) == 2:
    df["color"] = ["steelblue", "skyblue"]
else:
    df["color"] = ["steelblue"]
df["percentage"] = df["paymentAmount"] / df["paymentAmount"].sum()
df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n))
df["percentage"] = df['percentage'].astype(str)
df["percentage"] = df["percentage"].str.pad(35, side="left")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(width=figsize[0], height=figsize[1], toolbar_location=None, x_range=(-1.0, 1.0), y_range=(-1.0, 1.0),
           tooltips=[("percentage", "@percentage")], tools="hover")
pie_chart = p.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=0.5,
                    start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
                    line_color="white", fill_color='color', source=source)
labels = LabelSet(x="cos", y="sin", y_offset=0, text='percentage', text_align="center", angle=0, source=source,
                  render_mode='canvas')
p.add_layout(labels)

legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=dict(field="category"), renderers=[pie_chart])],
                location=(0, figsize[1] - 100))
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

p.axis.axis_label = None
p.axis.visible = False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None
save(p)
```

The produced pie chart is:

[image]