# Strange Labels on Bokeh Pie/Donut Chart

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm following the response in this question: [Adding labels in pie chart wedge in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892890/adding-labels-in-pie-chart-wedge-in-bokeh/54004446#54004446)

I'm trying to add labels to my Bokeh chart so users can see data values. For some reason, the chart is rendering like this:

[image: Pie Chart]

I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried commenting out the z variable to see if this made a difference.. it does not.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import export_png
from bokeh.models import LabelSet, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
import matplotlib as plt
from math import pi
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

lst = ['On_Time', 'All'] 

lst2 = [8, 85] 

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), 
               columns =['Column', 'Value']) 
df 

df['angle'] = df['value']/df['value'].sum() * 2*pi
df['angle']

df['color'] = ['#084594', '#2171b5']

#z=110*(df['value']/df['value'].sum())
#df['value']=z
#df

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="", toolbar_location=None,
           tools="", x_range=(-.5, .5))

p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=1,  inner_radius=0.15, outer_radius=0.25, direction="anticlock",
                start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='column', source=df)

df["value"] = df['value'].astype(str)
df["value"] = df["value"].str.pad(35, side = "left")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

labels = LabelSet(x=0, y=1, text='value', level='glyph',
        angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), source=source, render_mode='canvas')

p.add_layout(labels)

p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Comment: instead of connecting to your database (which no one can access), rewrite the question to include a hard-coded dataframe.

Comment: @PaulH I just added a snippet to display the Dataframe

Comment: The suggestion is to make the code sample itself be complete and runnable so that others can investigate directly.

Comment: @bigreddot Understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are "underneath" because you have set

```
level='glyph'
```

in the call to `LabelSet`. There is generally not very many reasons to disturb the default render levels. If you remove this, the label will show up "on top" the way annotations such as `LabelSet` are intended to.

Also note the "str padding" that the other answer used to position the label alignment. That's slightly hacky but serviceable. Font differences between viewers' browser might make small differences. The alternative is to compute actual, exact x, y positions around the circle where you want the labels to go.