# Adding labels in pie/donut chart using annual_wedge in bokeh 2.x

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a problem applying correctly aligned labelsets to a donut style chart created with `annual_wedge` glyphs in bokeh.

I have trouble aligning labels belonging to the categories of the "rings" of the donut chart "horizontaly", where horizontaly is the alignment of the label from the `inner_radius` of the `annual_wedge` to the `outer_radius`.
Currently labelsets doesn´t seem to have an `inner_radius` setting corresponding to an `annual_wedge` which makes applying and alignment of labelsets to annual wedges extremely difficult.

I was following the example in [Adding labels in pie chart wedge in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892890/adding-labels-in-pie-chart-wedge-in-bokeh) using string padding but this seems to be a very dirty hack to move the labels horizontally.

How can I apply labels to an annual_wedge in a aligned way corresponding to the inner_radius of the annual_wedge glyph?

Here is my code example:

```
# > gics_sector_data
gics_sector_data["gics_name"] = gics_sector_data["gics_name"].astype(str)
gics_sector_data["gics_name"] = gics_sector_data["gics_name"].str.pad(47, side = "left")

    # Sector Ring
    p.annular_wedge(x=9, y=9, inner_radius=0.8,outer_radius=2.5,
            start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
            line_color="white", fill_color='color', source=gics_sector_data)

    sourceSector = ColumnDataSource(gics_sector_data)
    labelsSector = LabelSet(x=9, y=9, text='gics_name',
                        angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), source=sourceSector, render_mode='canvas',
                        text_font_size="8pt", text_align='left',background_fill_color='white')
    p.add_layout(labelsSector)
```

In the image i set the background color of the labels to white so the alignmend and spacing of the lables can be better seen.

[image: example screenshot of bokeh annual_wedge labelset problem]]

Just for your info: this is the data to be displayed [Global Industry Classification Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compute the coordinates yourself.

Expanding on the linked example:

```py
from math import pi

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import LabelSet, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = {'United States': 157,
     'United Kingdom': 93,
     'Japan': 89,
     'China': 63,
     'Germany': 44,
     'India': 42,
     'Italy': 40,
     'Australia': 35,
     'Brazil': 32,
     'France': 31,
     'Taiwan': 31,
     'Spain': 29}

R = 0.4
data = (pd.Series(x)
        .reset_index(name='value')
        .rename(columns={'index': 'country'})
        .assign(end_angle=lambda d: np.cumsum(d['value'] / d['value'].sum() * 2 * pi),
                start_angle=lambda d: np.pad(d['end_angle'], (1, 0))[:-1],
                color=Category20c[len(x)],
                label_x=lambda d: R * 0.95 * np.cos(d['start_angle']),
                label_y=lambda d: R * 0.95 * np.sin(d['start_angle'])))

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p_range = (-R * 1.2, R * 1.2)
p_size = 500
p = figure(plot_height=p_size, plot_width=p_size, toolbar_location=None,
           x_range=p_range, y_range=p_range,
           tools="hover", tooltips="@country: @value")
for r in [p.xaxis, p.yaxis, p.grid]:
    r.visible = False

p.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=R,
        start_angle='start_angle', end_angle='end_angle',
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend_label='country', source=source)

p.add_layout(LabelSet(x='label_x', y='label_y', text='value', text_align='right',
                      angle='start_angle', source=source, render_mode='canvas'))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: What is R variable in R=0.4

Comment: It's the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eugene I was lead to the path of enlightment and was able to get the chart as I wanted.
I had to modify the calculation of the label positions by calculating the middle between the start angle and the end angle of a sector of the "donut" because I wanted to have the labels in the middle of each wedge.

I modified Eugenes example to this where "num" is just the value I use to calculate the relative width of each annual_wedge (Eugene uses 'value' in his example, I use num for occupied number of slots of each wedge of a total of similiar width slots on the 'donut', I hope this is clear enough):

```
R = 3
gics_sector_data= gics_sector_data.assign(
                end_angle=lambda d: np.cumsum(d['num'] / d['num'].sum() * 2 * pi),
                start_angle=lambda d: np.pad(d['end_angle'], (1, 0))[:-1],
                label_x=lambda d: R* 1.00 * np.cos(((d['end_angle']-d['start_angle'])/2)+d['start_angle']),
                label_y=lambda d: R* 1.00 * np.sin(((d['end_angle']-d['start_angle'])/2)+d['start_angle']),
                label_angle=lambda d: (((d['end_angle']-d['start_angle'])/2)+d['start_angle']))
```

Something about the 1.00 multiplication, you can move the labels away from the outer edge of the wedge by f.e. using 0.95.

Something aside: I shortened the label names by adding a label_shortname column because bokeh can not line wrap labels. The shortname will be used for the labels, the long name for the tooltip:

```
gics_sector_data['gics_name_short'] = gics_sector_data['gics_name'].str.slice(stop=20)
```

and then draw the annual_wedge like with the start_angles and end_anglescalculated:

```
# Sector Ring
p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=0, inner_radius=gics_sector_radius-ringWidth, outer_radius=gics_sector_radius,
                start_angle='start_angle', end_angle='end_angle',
                line_color="white", fill_color='color', source=gics_sector_data)
```

and finally draw the LabelSet with the label_x, label_y and label_angle calculated which will draw the label in the middle of the wedge, text_baseline='middle' is mandatory to achive a nice result:

```
sourceSector = ColumnDataSource(gics_sector_data)
labelsSector = LabelSet(x='label_x', y='label_y', text='gics_name_short',
                   angle='label_angle', source=sourceSector, render_mode='canvas',
                    text_font_size="7pt", text_align='right', text_baseline='middle')
p.add_layout(labelsSector)
```

and here the 99.999% perfect result [GICS result bokeh chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0SF6.png) , I hope this will help to create similar charts

Comment: Do you have any idea on why the labels are not aligned 100% accurately on diagonal parts of the image? Seems like the alignment is perfect only on the horizontal and vertical directions.

Comment: Maybe it is because the graph in the outer regions approaches a scale where the dpi of the screen and the image size is not good enough for accuracy in drawing angeled objects. If the resolution of the image will be higher, maybe everything will look better. But this is just a guess.